# Javascript building an object directly

Tags: javascript, object

**I have these values:**

```js
let buffer = {};
let value = 'value';
let x = 1;
let y = 2;
```

**This is what I want to do:**

```js
buffer[x][y].value = value;
```

**This is what I need to do, in order for it to work:**

```js
buffer[x] = {};
buffer[x][y] = {};
buffer[x][y].value = value;
```

My guess is that there is a better, maybe built in way to create an object like this in one step instead of three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My guess is that there is a better, maybe built in way to create an object like this in one step instead of three.

What you have is fine, but you can also do it with computed properties (I'm assuming you need the values from variables) and shorthand property notation (for `value`):

```js
let value = 'value';
let x = 1;
let y = 2;

let buffer = {
  [x]: {
    [y]: {
      value
    }
  }
};

console.log(buffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create nested object based on a set of keys, you could use [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight). Use the [rest parameters syntax](http://rest%20parameter%20syntax) to get the value and the array of paths as separate variables. Set the `value` as the `initialValue` parameter and add a level of nesting in each iteration

```js
const create = (value, ...paths) => paths.reduceRight((r, k) => ({ [k]: r }), value)

console.log(create("final value", "1", "2", "value"))
console.log(create("final value", "any", "number", "of", "keys"))
```

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah, I added another approach since your answer already covered that. From the accepted answer, OP is fine with creating a new object. `buffer` was just for demonstration probably

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
const buffer = {
  1: {
    2: {
      value: 'value'
    }
  }
};
```

If `x` and `y` are already defined, then use computed properties:

```js
let x = 1;
let y = 2;
const buffer = {
  [x]: {
    [y]: {
      value: 'value'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: If the values are fixed, not from the variables shown.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the given keys and assign the value at the last step.

```js
const
    setValue = (object, path, value) =>
        path.reduce((o, k, i, { length }) => o[k] = i + 1 === length
            ? value
            : o[k] || {}, object);

let buffer = {};
let value = 'value';
let x = 1;
let y = 2;

setValue(buffer, [x, y, value], value);
console.log(buffer);
```

Comment: Nina and her `reduce`... :-)

Comment: You've forgot to add `value` to the path.

Comment: @Titus, where do i missed this?

Comment: `"2": "value"` needs to be `"2": { "value": "value"}`.

Comment: The OP's final inner object is `{ value: "value" }`, and in your example is: `{ "2": value }`